# Input will be floating value and program return whole part and decimal value

Tags: c++, parsing, floating-point

I am trying to do an assignment of c++.

I have to do task to take input from user in floating datatype and  to give an output to separate the whole part of given value and decimal part without point.for example if user enter 4.456 and output should be whole part is 4 and decimal part without point is 456.

I have trying this but not sure what to do next.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float a,b;
    int c,d=0,z;

    cout<<"entre a number"<<endl;
    cin>>a;

    c=static_cast<int>(a);  
    b=a-c;
    b=z;
    cout<<z;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). You should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

A simple/primitive approach would be to first convert (cast) the `float`/`double` to `int`. This will drop the decimals get you the first part of your answer - the integer before the ".". Then you can simply subtract this integer from the original number and you'll be left with 0.xxxx - decide how many decimal values you want to print, then multiply this value by 10to the power of that number and cast to `int` again and print it.

Comment: i am trying to attempt it like
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
float a,b;
int c,d=0,z;
cout<<"entre a number"<<endl;
cin>>a;
c=static_cast<int>(a);

b=a-c;
b=z;
cout<<z;

is it right approch or guide me from here